# How to implement word-for-word predictive text within one cell in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I have a column in a table that will contain entire phrases with difficult words ("hypothetical exemplification of those akiophrastic words"). I have a list of most words that I expect will be used there.

I found a great solution [here](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2401-excel-drop-down-list-autocomplete.html) but it doesn't quite match my usecase. It works if you want to choose the content of your cell from a list of choices. I want to be able to get suggestions for the currently-typed word within the cell. So I write "hypoth" and click "hypothetical" from the dropdown, then I hit spacebar and start writing "exem" and want to get suggestions for that as well, and so on.

I will try changing the VBA code provided in my hyperlink above but I'm not sure I'll be successful. I'm open to any suggestion. It can also involve userforms although I doubt there is a way using them.

EDIT: On request, I'm summarizing the linked tutorial and posting its code.

It makes you create a Combo Box from the developer tools tab and name it TempCombo.

In the code for the worksheet, where the box is located, you write the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
'Update by Extendoffice: 2020/01/16
    Dim xCombox As OLEObject
    Dim xStr As String
    Dim xWs As Worksheet
    Dim xArr
     
    Set xWs = Application.ActiveSheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xCombox = xWs.OLEObjects("TempCombo")
    With xCombox
        .ListFillRange = ""
        .LinkedCell = ""
        .Visible = False
    End With
    If Target.Validation.Type = 3 Then
        Target.Validation.InCellDropdown = False
        Cancel = True
        xStr = Target.Validation.Formula1
        xStr = Right(xStr, Len(xStr) - 1)
        If xStr = "" Then Exit Sub
        With xCombox
            .Visible = True
            .Left = Target.Left
            .Top = Target.Top
            .Width = Target.Width + 5
            .Height = Target.Height + 5
            .ListFillRange = xStr
            If .ListFillRange = "" Then
                xArr = Split(xStr, ",")
                Me.TempCombo.List = xArr
            End If
            .LinkedCell = Target.Address
        End With
        xCombox.Activate
        Me.TempCombo.DropDown
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub TempCombo_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    Select Case KeyCode
        Case 9
            Application.ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
        Case 13
            Application.ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you add the code to your question please.  I've a phobia against clicking on external links.

Comment: Sure. It's done now.

Comment: Instead of a combobox you would likely need a textbox and a listbox if you want to maintain the whole text instead of having it replaced by the last chosen word

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using the linked code from my OP and Tim Williams's excellent code, this is the result I got to. To use this, you will have to adapt some lines. There were some really odd bugs which I fixed by adapting some parts. Also added control functionality with Return (+Shift), up and down keys.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim xText As OLEObject
    Dim xStr As String
    Dim xList As OLEObject
    Dim xWs As Worksheet
    Dim xArr
    Dim ListTarget As Range
    
    ' Suggestion box placement
    Set ListTarget = Target.Offset(2, 1)
     
    Set xWs = Application.ActiveSheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xText = xWs.OLEObjects("txt1")
    Set xList = xWs.OLEObjects("lstMatches")
    ' Every click lets the boxes disappear.
    With xText
        .ListFillRange = ""
        .LinkedCell = ""
        .Visible = False
    End With
    With xList
        .ListFillRange = ""
        .LinkedCell = ""
        .Visible = False
    End With
    ' Restrict where you want this functionality in your sheet here
    If Target.Validation.Type = 3 And Target.column = 10 And Target.row > 4 Then
        Target.Validation.InCellDropdown = False
        xStr = Target.Validation.Formula1
        xStr = Right(xStr, Len(xStr) - 1)
        If xStr = "" Then Exit Sub
        With xText
            .Visible = True
            .Left = Target.Left
            .Top = Target.Top
            .Width = Target.Width + 200 ' Size of text box
            .Height = Target.Height + 5 ' Make it a little taller for better readability
            .ListFillRange = ""
            'If .ListFillRange = "" Then
                'xArr = Split(xStr, ",")
                'Me.TempCombo.list = xArr
            'End If
            .LinkedCell = Target.Address
        End With
        With xList
            .Visible = True
            .Left = ListTarget.Left
            .Top = ListTarget.Top
            .Width = ListTarget.Width + 200 ' Size of suggestions box
            .Height = ListTarget.Height + 100
            If .ListFillRange = "" Then 'This loop fills the suggestions with the list from the validation formula, unless already changed by input
                xArr = Split(xStr, ",")
                xList.ListFillRange = xArr
            End If
        End With
        xText.Activate
        Me.lstMatches.Locked = False ' It randomly locked for me, just in case.
        ' The following two lines fix an obscure bug that made the suggestions un-clickable at random.
        ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToLeft:=1
        ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=1
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub lstMatches_Click()

    Dim word, pos As Long
    word = Me.lstMatches.value
    suspend = True ' disables the text change function for programmatic changes
    'try to replace the last "word" (or part of word) with the selected word
    pos = InStrRev(Me.txt1.text, " ")
    If pos > 0 Then
        Me.txt1.text = Left(Me.txt1.text, pos) & word
    Else
        Me.txt1.text = word
    End If
    Me.txt1.Activate
    suspend = False
End Sub

Private Sub txt1_Change()
    Dim txt As String, arr, last As String, allWords, r As Long
    
    Dim data_lastRow As Long
    data_lastRow = Worksheets("my_data").Cells(2, 5).End(xlDown).row
    
    If suspend Then Exit Sub 'don't respond to programmatic changes

    txt = Trim(Me.txt1.text)
    If Len(txt) = 0 Then
        Me.lstMatches.Clear
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    arr = Split(txt, " ")
    last = arr(UBound(arr))
    
    If Len(last) > 1 Then
        allWords = Worksheets("my_data").Range("E2:E" & CStr(data_lastRow)).value 'get the words list
        Me.lstMatches.Clear
        For r = 1 To UBound(allWords)
            If allWords(r, 1) Like last & "*" Then 'match on "starts with"
                Me.lstMatches.AddItem allWords(r, 1)
                If Me.lstMatches.ListCount = 15 Then Exit Sub ' limiting it to 15 suggestions
            End If
        Next r
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub txt1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    Select Case KeyCode
        Case 13
            If Shift = 0 Then
            Application.ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
            Else
            Application.ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Activate
            End If
        Case vbKeyDown
            Application.ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
        Case vbKeyUp
            Application.ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Activate
        Case vbKeyLeft
            Application.ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Activate
    End Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very basic example using a text box (txt1) and a listbox (lstMatches) on a worksheet:

```vb
Option Explicit

Dim suspend As Boolean

Private Sub lstMatches_Click()
    Dim word, pos As Long
    word = Me.lstMatches.Value
    suspend = True
    'try to replace the last "word" (or part of word) with the selected word
    pos = InStrRev(Me.txt1.Text, " ")
    If pos > 0 Then
        Me.txt1.Text = Left(Me.txt1.Text, pos) & " " & word
    Else
        Me.txt1.Text = word
    End If
    Me.txt1.Activate
    suspend = False
End Sub

Private Sub txt1_Change()
    Dim txt As String, arr, last As String, allWords, r As Long
    
    If suspend Then Exit Sub 'don't respond to programmatic changes
    
    txt = Trim(Me.txt1.Text)
    If Len(txt) = 0 Then 'is there any text?
        Me.lstMatches.Clear
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    arr = Split(txt, " ")
    last = arr(UBound(arr)) 'get the last word
    
    If Len(last) > 1 Then
        allWords = Me.Range("words").Value 'get the words list
        Me.lstMatches.Clear
        For r = 1 To UBound(allWords)
            If allWords(r, 1) Like last & "*" Then 'match on "starts with"
                Me.lstMatches.AddItem allWords(r, 1)
            End If
        Next r
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I took this and combined it with the code from my post to achieve exactly what I was looking for. I'll post my finished code for posterity because there are many additions and small changes.